# Conditional calculation of equation in new column

Tags: r, database, if-statement, merge, conditional-statements

I have 2 equations. On the basis of SEX the value of data$CB changes. Kindly check if the conditional loop is correct as it is not working.

if ( data$SEX==1) {
 data$CB= (140-data$AGE)*data$WT/(data$CRCL*72)}

else if ( data$SEX==0) {
  data$CB =(140-data$AGE)*data$WT/(data$CRCL*72)*0.85 }

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `ifelse` command like so

`data$CB<-ifelse(data$SEX==1, 140-data$AGE)*data$WT/(data$CRCL*72), 140-data$AGE)*data$WT/(data$CRCL*72)*0.85)`

This will check every row in `data` and if `SEX==1` it will do the first part (after the first comma) and if it is false it will do the part after the second comma.

Comment: This has resulted in all NA values

Comment: I am guessing that there are some NA values in `data$Age`,  `data$WT$` and /or `data$CRCL`  - is that correct? Are you trying to use different values  of those for each row?

Comment: No there are all values available but the calculation resulted in all zero